# Operation on two List<>

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am stuck with this for quite a while. What I want my program to do :

I will have two lists. One of quantity and one of price. I want to multiply two according to their serial(example : quantity[i] * price[i]) and add the multiplication result together and get a specific number lets say I add them and I get 100 but I want 101.123 and the way I want to achieve is adding 0.001 to the first price number (I cant touch the quantity number) and check if it matches the answer I wanted. I cant add more than 5 so if it fails to get the number from the first number I want to move to the second one and leave the first one as it was before. Any one? Here's where i have gotten.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ultimateproject_beginner_ {
    class Program {
        static List<decimal> QuantityList() {
            Console.WriteLine("Quantity");
            Console.WriteLine();
            List<decimal> quantityList = new List<decimal>();
            for (;;) {
                string stringQuantityNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                decimal quantityNumber = 0M;
                if (stringQuantityNumber == "done") {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(stringQuantityNumber, out quantityNumber)) {
                        quantityList.Add(quantityNumber);
                    }
                }
            }//end of for loop
            return quantityList;
        }

        static List<decimal> PriceList() {
            Console.WriteLine("Price");
            List<decimal> priceList = new List<decimal>();
            for (;;) {
                string stringPriceNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                decimal priceNumber = 0M;
                if (stringPriceNumber == "done") {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(stringPriceNumber, out priceNumber)) {
                        priceList.Add(priceNumber);

                    }
                }
            }//end of for loop
            return priceList;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<decimal> quantityList = QuantityList();
            List<decimal> priceList = PriceList();
            decimal destination = 101.123M;
            decimal sum = 0M;
            for (int i = 0; i < quantityList.Count; i++) {
                decimal product = priceList[i] * quantityList[i];
                sum = sum + product;
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to make it work with some nested for loops but I get stuck where I have to multiply the new value with all other ones.

What I get: 100, What I want : 101.123 How: by adding 0.001 to priceList and check if the sum is 101.123

Comment: I didn't understand your logic. Why do you want `101.123` instead calculated value `100` ? Tax? And This belongs to CodeReview Website. Anyway you might need to provide a sample input, desired output and the current output

Comment: I cannot figure out what you're trying to do here. Here's what would help: make a *worked example*.  Give us an example of a list of ten quantities and ten prices, and then show us how you would solve this problem *by hand*.  Once we can see how to solve the problem by hand we can help you translate that into a program.

Comment: @FirstStep: CodeReview is for code that works. This code doesn't work.

Comment: @eric maybe he needs to state the error then. What I read was that he tried a way and he is looking for another better way. Logical errors

Comment: If what you're trying to do is even a little bit complex then it's important to state it very clearly. If it takes more than once reading over it to begin to understand then people are going to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to dealing with this is to compute the total on first path, then figure out how many additions you would need, and then perform the adjustments. Note that it is possible that you wouldn't be able to reach the desired target, because the max value that you can add is limited by $0.05 times the total quantity of all items ordered. If the sum is $100, you need $101.23, but the order has only ten items in all, the highest you can get with $0.04 per item is $100.50.

You can compute the total using LINQ:

```
var total = quantityList.Zip(priceList, (q, p) => q*p).Sum();
```

Compute the value remaining to be assigned, and go through the individual rows, and do the adjustment until `remaining` drops to zero:

```
var remaining = destination - total;
for (int i = 0; remaining > 0 && i < quantityList.Count; i++) {
    var quantity = quantityList[i];
    // Avoid crashes on zero quantity
    if (quantity == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // We cannot assign more than quantity * 0.05
    var toAssign = Math.Min(remaining, quantity * 0.05);
    remaining -= toAssign;
    // Split the amount being assigned among the items
    priceList[i] += toAssign / quantity;
}
if (remaining > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to distribute {0:C}", remaining);
}
```

**Note:** Ideally, you should consider creating a class representing quantity/price pairs, rather than using [parallel lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array).

Comment: I will try to make it a bit clearer to you: I dont want to add 0.001 to all the number but incremeant the first item on priceList and check if it matches my destination. I will increament it by 0.001 5000 times if I dont get the result with in 5000 time I want to move in to the next one. I think a nested for loop can do that.

Comment: @RezaTaibur You do not need a nested loop, and you do not need to go by 0.001. If you have your target, you can simply divide by the quantity, and obtain the number of times that you would have to increment automatically.

Comment: @RezaTaibur Consider an example: let's say that your total is $1, you need $1.01, and all you have is a list of two items at $0.50 each. You can iterate five times, trying $0.501, $0.502, $0.503, and $0.504 until you reach the correct answer of $0.505, or you could divide $0.01 by two, the number of items, and get the correct result right away.

Answer (score 0):

After sum is calculated, compare it to destination. If sum < destination, then calculate number of 0.001 increments needed as count = (destination - sum) / 0.001. If this is less than 5, then add this many to the first price, otherwise add five of them (0.005), and then subtract 5 from count. If count > 0 then repeat the process for the second price, etc. If count is greater than pricelist.Count * 5, you can't reach the destination price.